# Using Include with Intersect/Union/Exclude in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

What seemed that it should be a relatively straight-forward task has turned into something of a surprisingly complex issue. To the point that I'm starting to think that my methodology perhaps is simply out of scope with the capabilities of Linq.

What I'm trying to do is piece-together a Linq query and then invoke `.Include()` in order to pull-in values from a number of child entities. For example, let's say I have these entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say I want to perform a query to retrieve records from `Parent`, where `Name` is some value and `Location` is some other value, and then include `Child` records, too. But for whatever reason I don't know the query values for `Name` and `Location` at the same time, so I have to take two separate queryables and join them, such:

```
MyDbContext C = new MyDbContext();
var queryOne = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Name == myName);
var queryTwo = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Location == myLocation);
var finalQuery = queryOne.Intersect(queryTwo);
```

That works fine, producing results exactly as if I had just done:

```
var query = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Name == myName && p.Location = myLocation);
```

And similarly, I can:

```
var finalQuery = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);
```

To give me results just as if I had:

```
var query = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Name == myName || p.Location = myLocation);
```

What I cannot do, however, once the `Intersect()` or `Union()` is applied, however, is then go about mapping the `Child` using `Include()`, as in:

```
finalQuery.Include(p => p.Children);
```

This code will compile, but produces results as follows:

1. In the case of a `Union()`, a result set will be produced, but no `Child` entities will be enumerated.
2. In the case of an `Intersect()`, a run-time error is generated upon attempt to apply `Include()`, as follows:

> Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]' of method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]
>   Intersect[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])'

The thing that baffles me is that this code will work exactly as expected:

```
var query = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Name == myName).Where(p => p.Location == myLocation);
query.Include(p => p.Children);
```

I.e., with the results as desired, including the `Child` entities enumerated.

Comment: So why don't you just use `var query = C.Parent.Where(p => p.Name == myName); query = query.Where(p => p.Location == myLocation); query = query.Include(p => p.Children);`? Is there something that you don't have there?

Comment: Well, that will work for an OR (Union) condition joining the queries, but not an AND (Intersect).

Comment: Quite the contrary. Two calls to `Where` perform an `AND` on the final query

Comment: Right, that's what I meant to say... Works for AND condition but not OR. And I need both.

Comment: At some point you have both values, don't you? Wait until you do, then.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it's not quite that simple. I'm using a very simplified, generic case, here, to illustrate the nature of the problem. It's actually a very complex graph of criteria that I need to process, and there's no way to get around the need to procedurally construct the query, on the fly. In that process, there's no way to get around needing to join two pre-existing queryables via OR.

Comment: What happens if you try the union using `Include` after both `Where` calls?

Comment: Same result -- have tried probably every possible permutation in terms of execution order, in that regard. It's very odd.

Comment: So why don't you just forget about include and load the children after the query? It should normally be the same as using include

Comment: Well, because I'm rendering a rather large result set through a web service API, and it is actually a deeply-nested object graph. It would be a crazily involved and onerous task to get an initial result set, and then go back over that, iteratively populating all the child objects. If it were as simple as in my example, sure, but my actual case is many, many times more complex.

Comment: Is it so? Your last comment doesn't really make sense. You either have  the values or you don't, you have the query or you don't. We can only answer what you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time has gone by, but this `.Include` problem still exists in EF 6. However, there is a workaround: Append every child request with `.Include` before intersecting/Unionizing.

```cs
MyDbContext C = new MyDbContext();
var queryOne = db.Parents.Where(p => p.Name == parent.Name).Include("Children");
var queryTwo = db.Parents.Where(p => p.Location == parent.Location).Include("Children");
var finalQuery = queryOne.Intersect(queryTwo);
```

As stated by @Ivan Stoev, Intersection/Union is done with after-fetched data, while `.Include` is ok at request time.

So, as of now, you have this one option available.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is why `Include` can't be applied to the final query. You don't answer that question. This is merely a work-around.

Comment: The OP asked about "piece-together a Linq query and then invoke `.Include()` in order to pull-in values from a number of child entities".
I answered a workaround: "piece-together Linq queries that were populated with their child entities to pull-in values".

I mentionned this as a workaround: That's one of the some options available to work around the fact `Include` can't be applied to the final query. Indeed, it's a workaround. IMHO, still a better answer than `you have no options`.

Comment: Exactly, "piece-together a Linq query and *then* invoke `.Include()`".

Comment: I hade quite exactly the same question as OP, and as such, this workaround popped up for me. Thought that "There's a workaround" would be a friendlier answer than "No options.".
Is there a problem of some sort with my answer?
- Note that having two `.Where` populated before `.Union`/`.Intersect` them is low performance; but that's another concern (I reworked my own query accordingly, I'm no one to judge OP's example use-case).

Answer (score 6):

> my methodology perhaps is simply out of scope with the capabilities of Linq

The problem is not LINQ, but EF Core query translation, and specifically the lack of `Intersect` / `Union` / `Concat` / `Except` method SQL translation, tracked by [#6812 Query: Translate IQueryable.Concat/Union/Intersect/Except/etc. to server](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6812).

Shortly, such queries currently use [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval), which with combination of how the EF Core handles `Include` leads to many unexpected runtime exceptions (like your case #2) or wrong behaviors (like [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) in your case #1).

So while your approach technically perfectly makes sense, according to the EF Core team leader response

> Changing this to producing a single SQL query on the server isn't currently a top priority

so this currently is not even planned for 3.0 release, although there are plans to change (rewrite) the whole query translation pipeline, which might allow implementing that as well.

For now, you have no options. You may try processing the query expression trees yourself, but that's a complicated task and you'll probably find why it is not implemented yet :) If you can convert your queries to the equivalent single query with combined `Where` condition, then applying `Include` will be fine.

---

P.S. Note that even now your approach technically "works" w/o `Include`, prefomance wise the way it is evaluated client side makes it absolutely non equivalent of the corresponding single query.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I had looked around for known issues such as that and could not find any. Looks like I will need to alter my approach, significantly. I will have to generate some fairly complex code to append the Where() conditions, etc. Or, perhaps there is some way to use delegates to create the complex conditional expressions I need. At any rate, it's good to know that this is an internal issue and I can now stop trying to make it work. Thanks! :-)

Comment: In looking over your answer again, I wanted to add that my goal is, indeed, to aim for the execution of a single query, on the server. My baseline is always to kinda blindly accept that this is always the best approach. I always dislike it if my logic requires that I go get some results from the server, and then have to do something with one or more sets of results to get what I ultimately want. I feel that the ORM should be handling all of that for me, properly. I also don't like to formulate big, unwieldy Linq queries, but it's looking like that's what I'm going to be doing...

Comment: @MichaelDoleman Absolutely. I agree that ORM should handle that for you. It's IMHO one of the major failures of the current EF Core stage, In contrast, the old good EF6 would handle it perfectly for you, as expected. EF Core currently is for, well, simple CRUD and no more than that.